# Invoke Webservice with yield return on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, return, webservice-client, yield

i'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app and I use Windows Live authentication to access the user contacts. I have a webservice, with the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<LiveIDContact> GetContactsInformationYield(string LocationID, string DelegationToken)
    {
        string uriTemplate = "https://livecontacts.services.live.com/@L@{0}/rest/LiveContacts/Contacts";
        var xdoc = WindowsLiveContactAPIRequest(LocationID, DelegationToken, uriTemplate);
        var contacts = (from contact in xdoc.Descendants("Contact")
                        select contact).ToArray();

        foreach (var con in contacts)
        {
            RetrieveCID(LocationID, DelegationToken, con);
            LiveIDContact c = new LiveIDContact()
            {
                ID = con.Element("ID").Value,
                DisplayName = con.Element("Profiles").Element("Personal").Element("DisplayName").Value,
                CID = (con.Element("CID") != null ? con.Element("CID").Value : "")

            };

            yield return c;
        }

    }
```

How i invoke the methode in the app:

```
public void GetContactInformationAsync()
    {
        LiveIDClient.GetContactsInformationYieldAsync(LocationID, ConsentToken);
    }
```

Here is the problem, when I invoke this methode and i wait on the complete event. It takes 4 to 5 minutes to update the list of contacts in my app.(Performance issue). Is there any way that an event occurs on every yield return ? So i can update my list from that event?

I couldn't find the answer anywhere so lets hope somebody knows the answer.

Comment: You're calling GetContactsInformationYieldAsync in the GetContactInformationAsync method. You haven't posted that method, and nothing's currently calling GetContactsInformationYield.

Comment: I'm calling GetContactsInformationYieldAsync(LocationID, ConsentToken); 
The Async part is added by visual studio because it's windows phone, every service invoke is Asynch.
The method call works, only problem is it takes 4 to 5 minutes to load all contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Is this making a separate HTTP call for every single contact? If so, then I think you simply need to redesign the webservice so that it makes a call for, say, every hundred contacts.

Comment: Every single contact is returned after the RetrieveCID methode, this methode does a webrequest and gets a cid, takes op 1 or 2 seconds on high speed connection, so i think its best to return every single contact.